# Cloning form inputs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

There are numerous similar questions to mine, but none that address the specifics, unfortunately.

I have *multiple* forms on a page, all with the same structure:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <select></select>
    </div>
    <div class="blank-container">
        <div class="form-group blank-group">
            <select></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-blank"></button>
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

The initial `.form-group` within each `form` has a pre-populated `select`, but the `select` within `.blank-group` is empty. When the `.add-blank` button is pressed, I want to `clone()` the last `.blank-group` and append it to the `.blank-container`.

I've managed this before using `id`s on a single form with the following code:

```
$("#add-blank").click(function() {
    $(".blank-group").last().clone().appendTo("#blank-container");
});
```

But now I have numerous forms on the same page with the same structure, I need to work with a specific `.blank-container` and I'm having troubles. This is what I have tried:

```
$(".add-blank").click(function() {
    blankGroup = $(this).closest("form").find(".blank-container").find(".blank-group").last();
    blankContainer = $(this).closest("form").find(".blank-container");
    blankGroup.clone().appendTo(blankContainer);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation and traversal. Event delegation for the button press, and traversal to find things *relative to* the button:

```
$("selector-for-the-overall-container").on("click", ".add-blank", function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.find(".blank-group").last().clone().appendTo(form.find(".blank-container"));
});
```

`$("selector-for-the-overall-container")` *could* be `$(document)`, but usually there's an element that's a bit closer to the things you want to capture the event on.

**Live Example**:

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".add-blank", function() {
  var form = $(this).closest('form');
  form.find(".blank-group").last().clone().appendTo(form.find(".blank-container"));
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <select></select>
    </div>
    <div class="blank-container">
      <div class="form-group blank-group">
        This is the "blank" group
        <select></select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="add-blank">Add</button>
    <button type="submit"></button>
  </form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I should say you don't need event delegation if all of those buttons will already exist when your code runs. If that's the case, you could do this:

```
$(".add-blank").click(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.find(".blank-group").last().clone().appendTo(form.find(".blank-container"));
});
```

...but it sounded like things were fairly dynamic, so that's why I went for delegation.

Comment: Actually, sorry, just "processed" the code at the end of the question. That code should be working **if** the buttons exist when it runs; if not, then it may well be that you need event delegation (the beginning of the answer above).

Comment: The code works perfectly for me in a fiddle and on SO, but still isn't working on my page. Must be something else interfering with it. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: @mpdc: Ugh, sorry to hear that. Since the answer basically is just what you already had (again, sorry about that), sounds like it would be best if I deleted the answer and you deleted the question. If you reach a point where you have an [MCVE](/help/mcve) but still don't know what's wrong, post a new question and I (or someone else) will be happy to help. Good luck with it!

Comment: The problem was the `.add-blank` button, believe it or not. For some reason, when it resided inside the form inside a Bootstrap Modal, it caused problems. Moving it outside of the `form` tags it works fine!

Comment: @mpdc: How bizarre! Glad you figured it out, although I can't begin to account for that behavior. :-) Just for my own edification, can you post an MCVE of that? I can't see how that would cause trouble (not with the `type="button"` you have on it)... Also, since this wasn't the answer, probably best to unaccept. (Sorry for any hassle.)